# Heroku Error Deploying, Conda Related Error

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli

I am deploying my first application to Heroku and am receiving the following error. It is a Django application

```
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement conda==4.6.14 (from -r /tmp/.../requirements.txt (line 17)) (from versions: 3.0.6, 3.5.0, 3.7.0, 3.17.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.1.2, 4.1.6, 4.2.6, 4.2.7, 4.3.13, 4.3.16)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for conda==4.6.14 (from -r /tmp/.../requirements.txt (line 17))
```

Line 17 of requirements.txt is `/Downloads`

What exactly does this error mean?

Comment: why are you trying to install conda on heroku, is there a particular need for it

Comment: honestly maybe not, I've never uploaded to a website before and I'm not good with managing virtual environments and such. How do I exclude conda within the requirements.txt file? @iklinac

Comment: or how do i exclude it? @iklinac